# Find nearest latitude/longitude with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, coordinates, geospatial

I have latitude and longitude and I want to pull the record from the database, which has nearest latitude and longitude by the distance, if that distance gets longer than specified one, then don't retrieve it.

**Table structure:**

```
id
latitude
longitude
place name
city
country
state
zip
sealevel
```

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate of the [proximity search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260335/proximity-search/260347#260347) question.

Comment: There is a set of slides by Alexander Rubin on [Geo (proximity) search with MySQL](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf) (PDF link)

Comment: Beware of the answers here.  Most cannot use any index, hence perform poorly for large datasets.  Some are limited to non-spherical distance computation, thereby being not useful in may global applications.

Comment: Further discussion, including discussion of scaling, precision, and 5 competing techniques: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: If the query says `HAVING distance < ...`, then the query is likely to be checking every row and computing the distance for each one.  (Slow and not scalable.)

Answer (score 271):

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (latitude - [startlat]), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * ([startlng] - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM TableName HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance;
```

where **[starlat]** and **[startlng]** is the position where to start measuring the distance.

Comment: Just a performance note, it's best to not sqrt the distance variable but instead square the '25' test value... later sqrt the results that have passed if you need to show the distance

Comment: What would be the same query for the distance to be in meters ? (which is currently in miles, right?)

Comment: Lattitude is measured in degrees. not miles or meters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude

Comment: What measurement is that 25?

Comment: Just to clarify here 69.1 is the conversion factor for miles to latitude degrees.  57.3 is roughly 180/pi, so that's conversion from degrees to radians, for the cosine function.  25 is the search radius in miles.  This is the formula to use when using decimal degrees and statute miles.

Comment: Additionally, it does not take into account the curvature of the earth.  This would not be an issue for short search radii.  Otherwise Evan's and Igor's answers are more complete.

Comment: @JohnVance So the result distance is in miles, right? How to convert that for kilometers, for example? Also Igor's answer takes in account the radius of the earth but it's tooo slow. I got two seconds for Kalethas's answer but for Igor's answer I got like 15! Then what you mean when you say "short" distances?

Comment: @PatrickBassut , I know this is way late, but for others out there, if you need your "AS distance" to be in kilometers, you just need Km/degree of earth. Since Kaletha has already given you 69.1 miles/deg, then the change would be ~111.2km. [description](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm). Also, just FYI, do not fiddle with the 57.3 value, as stated above, it is a conversion factor for degree to radian.

Comment: @PatrickBassut, regarding your second question, what the others mean by "short" distances is the drawback of Kaletha's method. The math behind the function assumes that two points lie on a flat, rectangular grid. Obviously, the earth is round, so if you need the distance value to be accurate when comparing distances, say, between two coasts of the US, then this would not be accurate. [distance in cartesian coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points). Although Igor's is really slow due to all the calculations, it will give you "exact" miles

Comment: On Postgres it works only if i remove HAVING clause. `Error: the column distance does not exist`. Why?

Comment: You cant use distance in HAVING , because distance is not a real column of table,.

Comment: What I should do to set the max distance to 100km ? Is 25 the miles ?

Answer (score 105):

## Google's solution:

### Creating the Table

When you create the MySQL table, you want to pay particular attention to the lat and lng attributes. With the current zoom capabilities of Google Maps, you should only need 6 digits of precision after the decimal. To keep the storage space required for your table at a minimum, you can specify that the lat and lng attributes are floats of size (10,6). That will let the fields store 6 digits after the decimal, plus up to 4 digits before the decimal, e.g. -123.456789 degrees. Your table should also have an id attribute to serve as the primary key.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL ,
  `address` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lat` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
  `lng` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

### Populating the Table

After creating the table, it's time to populate it with data. The sample data provided below is for about 180 pizzarias scattered across the United States. In phpMyAdmin, you can use the IMPORT tab to import various file formats, including CSV (comma-separated values). Microsoft Excel and Google Spreadsheets both export to CSV format, so you can easily transfer data from spreadsheets to MySQL tables through exporting/importing CSV files.

```sql
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too','939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA','37.386339','-122.085823');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Amici\'s East Coast Pizzeria','790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA','37.38714','-122.083235');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Kapp\'s Pizza Bar & Grill','191 Castro St, Mountain View, CA','37.393885','-122.078916');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Round Table Pizza: Mountain View','570 N Shoreline Blvd, Mountain View, CA','37.402653','-122.079354');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Tony & Alba\'s Pizza & Pasta','619 Escuela Ave, Mountain View, CA','37.394011','-122.095528');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Oregano\'s Wood-Fired Pizza','4546 El Camino Real, Los Altos, CA','37.401724','-122.114646');
```

### Finding Locations with MySQL

To find locations in your markers table that are within a certain radius distance of a given latitude/longitude, you can use a SELECT statement based on the Haversine formula. The Haversine formula is used generally for computing great-circle distances between two pairs of coordinates on a sphere. An in-depth mathemetical explanation is given by Wikipedia and a good discussion of the formula as it relates to programming is on Movable Type's site.

Here's the SQL statement that will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate. It calculates the distance based on the latitude/longitude of that row and the target latitude/longitude, and then asks for only rows where the distance value is less than 25, orders the whole query by distance, and limits it to 20 results. To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371.

```sql
SELECT 
id, 
(
   3959 *
   acos(cos(radians(37)) * 
   cos(radians(lat)) * 
   cos(radians(lng) - 
   radians(-122)) + 
   sin(radians(37)) * 
   sin(radians(lat )))
) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 28 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20;
```

This one is to find latitudes and longitudes in a distance less than 28 miles.

Another one is to find them in a distance between 28 and 29 miles:

```sql
SELECT 
id, 
(
   3959 *
   acos(cos(radians(37)) * 
   cos(radians(lat)) * 
   cos(radians(lng) - 
   radians(-122)) + 
   sin(radians(37)) * 
   sin(radians(lat )))
) AS distance 
FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 29 and distance > 28 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0, 20;
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#creating-the-map

Comment: Should it be `HAVING distance < 25` as we querying locations within a radius of 25 miles ?

Comment: it should be > 25 , then it will search all records

Comment: are you Sure @vidurpunj about > 25 ?

Comment: I tried the sql query using: distance < 25 but found no results .. as the sample markers distances all are above 25 ...

Comment: 37, -122 coordinate, is this latitude and longitude for position from where we need to find the distance?

Comment: This sometimes yields a null distance instead of 0.0 when the record's latitude and longitude are identical to those included in the formula.  For example, latitude +35.682395 and longitude +139.792022 yields null distance.  I used coalesce(distance,0) to treat the null as zero.  I haven't researched further, but my pre-existing latitude/longitude columns are decimal (not float).

Comment: On Postgres, it works only if I remove the HAVING clause. `Error: the column distance does not exist.` Why? Any alternate suggestions?

Comment: Why will we need `id` as primary key? We can't we use lat and lng as our primary key?

Comment: "floats of size (10,6) ... will let the fields store 6 digits after the decimal, plus up to 4 digits before the decimal," -- Not true.  Instead, `FLOAT` is limited to about 7 _significant_ digits.  That is sufficient for most uses.  Toss the `(10,6)`; it is deprecated in 8.0.17 and will be removed later.

Comment: so far this is the quickest query. it is 7~8% faster than https://stackoverflow.com/a/5548877/4826981

Answer (score 41):

The original answers to the question are good, but newer versions of mysql (MySQL 5.7.6 on) support geo queries, so you can now use built in functionality rather than doing complex queries.

You can now do something like:

```
select *, ST_Distance_Sphere( point ('input_longitude', 'input_latitude'), 
                              point(longitude, latitude)) * .000621371192 
          as `distance_in_miles` 
  from `TableName`
having `distance_in_miles` <= 'input_max_distance'
 order by `distance_in_miles` asc
```

The results are returned in `meters`. So if you want in `KM` simply use `.001` instead of `.000621371192` (which is for miles).

[MySql docs are here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html)

Comment: If possible please add mysql version in answer.

Comment: `ST_Distance_Sphere` doesn't exist in my host's install (`mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.23-MariaDB`). I read somewhere to substitute `ST_Distance` but the distances are way off.

Comment: @ashleedawg - From the version, I think you're using MariaDB, which is a fork of mysql.  From [this conversation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183930/mysql-changing-output-unit-of-st-distance-function) it looks like MariaDB hasn't implemented `ST_Distance_Sphere`

Comment: This answer should be higher up, as it's the only one that uses the "new" functionality and results in a much nicer query. Although to be honest I'm puzzled by the amount of answers that default to miles instead of the metric system; at least this one bothers to show how to switch between the two.

Comment: works great!
I coded stuff like this several times and it was always ...
But this one was in, out, works!
Thank you!
I have an issue left, i have three tables with locations.
Any idea how to run this select over all of them?

Answer (score 33):

Here is my full solution implemented in PHP.

This solution uses the Haversine formula as presented in http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL.

It should be noted that the Haversine formula experiences weaknesses around the poles. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054282/2268807) shows how to implement the [vincenty Great Circle Distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae) to get around this, however I chose to just use Haversine because it's good enough for my purposes.

I'm storing latitude as DECIMAL(10,8) and longitude as DECIMAL(11,8). Hopefully this helps!

#### showClosest.php

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Use the Haversine Formula to display the 100 closest matches to $origLat, $origLon
 * Only search the MySQL table $tableName for matches within a 10 mile ($dist) radius.
 */
include("./assets/db/db.php"); // Include database connection function
$db = new database(); // Initiate a new MySQL connection
$tableName = "db.table";
$origLat = 42.1365;
$origLon = -71.7559;
$dist = 10; // This is the maximum distance (in miles) away from $origLat, $origLon in which to search
$query = "SELECT name, latitude, longitude, 3956 * 2 * 
          ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat - latitude)*pi()/180/2),2)
          +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(latitude*pi()/180)
          *POWER(SIN(($origLon-longitude)*pi()/180/2),2))) 
          as distance FROM $tableName WHERE 
          longitude between ($origLon-$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and ($origLon+$dist/cos(radians($origLat))*69) 
          and latitude between ($origLat-($dist/69)) 
          and ($origLat+($dist/69)) 
          having distance < $dist ORDER BY distance limit 100"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name']." > ".$row['distance']."<BR>";
}
mysql_close($db);
?>
```

#### ./assets/db/db.php

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Class to initiate a new MySQL connection based on $dbInfo settings found in dbSettings.php
 *
 * @example $db = new database(); // Initiate a new database connection
 * @example mysql_close($db); // close the connection
 */
class database{
    protected $databaseLink;
    function __construct(){
        include "dbSettings.php";
        $this->database = $dbInfo['host'];
        $this->mysql_user = $dbInfo['user'];
        $this->mysql_pass = $dbInfo['pass'];
        $this->openConnection();
        return $this->get_link();
    }
    function openConnection(){
    $this->databaseLink = mysql_connect($this->database, $this->mysql_user, $this->mysql_pass);
    }

    function get_link(){
    return $this->databaseLink;
    }
}
?>
```

#### ./assets/db/dbSettings.php

```
<?php
$dbInfo = array(
    'host'      => "localhost",
    'user'      => "root",
    'pass'      => "password"
);
?>
```

It may be possible to increase performance by using a MySQL stored procedure as suggested by the "Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL" article posted above.

I have a database of ~17,000 places and the query execution time is 0.054 seconds.

Comment: How can I obtain the distance in Km or Meters? Regards!

Comment: WARNING. Excelent solution, but it has a bug. All the `abs` should be removed. There is no need to take the abs value when converting from degrees to radians, and, even if you did, you are doing it to just one of the latitudes. Please edit it so it fixes the bug.

Comment: And for anyone who wants this in meters:
Convert 3956 miles to kilometers: Earth's radius;
Convert 69 miles to kilometers: the aproxímate length of 1 degree latitude in km;
And input the distance in kilometers.

Comment: Should be able to exchange the `3956` with `6371` to have the results come up in km's as that is the earth's radius in KM's.

Comment: And replace `69` with `111,044736` (forgot that in above comment)

Comment: Hi, I just implemented your method for calculating distance. I would just like to know what is the margin of error in this formula? For example, for the same value of latitude and longitude I am getting a distance of 1.85 mile whereas it should be 0.

Comment: *"WARNING. Excelent solution, but it has a bug."* @Chango i know this is a old answer but when you see the possible SQL injection locations in this code you would/could not really worry about the `abs()` function.

Comment: The scribd link is now behind a paywall. Better to link to the source, which has been updated from time to time: http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf

Comment: This worked for me and i tried lots solutions but this one save my day. Thank you

Answer (score 27):

Just in case you are lazy like me, here's a solution amalgamated from this and other answers on SO.

```
set @orig_lat=37.46; 
set @orig_long=-122.25; 
set @bounding_distance=1;

SELECT
*
,((ACOS(SIN(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS(@orig_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS((@orig_long - `long`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance` 
FROM `cities` 
WHERE
(
  `lat` BETWEEN (@orig_lat - @bounding_distance) AND (@orig_lat + @bounding_distance)
  AND `long` BETWEEN (@orig_long - @bounding_distance) AND (@orig_long + @bounding_distance)
)
ORDER BY `distance` ASC
limit 25;
```

Comment: what exactly does `bounding_distance` represent? does this value limit the results to a mile amount?  so in this case it will return results within 1 mile?

Comment: @ bounding_distance is in degrees here, and is used to speed up calculations by limiting the effective search region.  For example, if you know your user is in a certain city, and you know you have a few points within that city, you can safely set your bounding distance to a few degrees.

Comment: Which geographical distance formula is this using?

Comment: The "bounding box" is being used in the `WHERE` to make it possible to use `INDEX(lat, lng), INDEX(lng, lat)`, but it is sub-optimal because `@bounding_distance` needs to be adjusted by dividing by `COS(@orig_lat)`.

Answer (score 13):

Easy one ;)

```
SELECT * FROM `WAYPOINTS` W ORDER BY
ABS(ABS(W.`LATITUDE`-53.63) +
ABS(W.`LONGITUDE`-9.9)) ASC LIMIT 30;
```

Just replace the coordinates with your required ones. The values have to be stored as double. This ist a working MySQL 5.x example.

Cheers

Comment: No idea why upvote, OP wants to limit and order by certain distance, not limit by 30 and order by `dx+dy`

Comment: This did it for me. It's not what the OP wanted, but it's what I wanted, so thank you for answering! :)

Comment: outermost ABS() is sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, it show the nearest points to provided coordinates (within 50 km). It works perfectly:

```
SELECT m.name,
    m.lat, m.lon,
    p.distance_unit
             * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(m.lat))
             * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(m.lon))
             + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(m.lat)))) AS distance_in_km
FROM <table_name> AS m
JOIN (
      SELECT <userLat> AS latpoint, <userLon> AS longpoint,
             50.0 AS radius, 111.045 AS distance_unit
     ) AS p ON 1=1
WHERE m.lat
BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND m.lon BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
    AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
ORDER BY distance_in_km
```

Just change `<table_name>`. `<userLat>` and `<userLon>`

You can read more about this solution here: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for things like the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574691/mysql-great-circle-distance-haversine-formula) as well.

There's other ones but this is the most commonly cited.

If you're looking for something even more robust, you might want to look at your databases GIS capabilities. They're capable of some cool things like telling you whether a point (City) appears within a given polygon (Region, Country, Continent).

Comment: It is indeed the most cited, but many articles refer to old computing hardware when it comes to statements about inaccurate computing using other methods. See also http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#cosine-law

Answer (score 4):

Check this code based on the article [Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL](https://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL):

**Example: find the 10 nearest hotels to my current location in a 10 miles radius:**

```
#Please notice that (lat,lng) values mustn't be negatives to perform all calculations

set @my_lat=34.6087674878572; 
set @my_lng=58.3783670308302;
set @dist=10; #10 miles radius

SELECT dest.id, dest.lat, dest.lng,  3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@my_lat -abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@my_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.lat) *  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@my_lng - abs(dest.lng)) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2))
) as distance
FROM hotel as dest
having distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance limit 10;

#Also notice that distance are expressed in terms of radius.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Find nearest Users to my:**

*Distance in meters*

Based in [Vincenty's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae)

i have User table:

```
+----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| id | email                 | name    | location_lat | location_long |
+----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| 13 | xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com | Isaac   | 17.2675625   | -97.6802361   |
| 14 | xxxx@xxxxxxx.com.mx   | Monse   | 19.392702    | -99.172596    |
+----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

sql:

```
-- my location:  lat   19.391124   -99.165660
SELECT 
(ATAN(
    SQRT(
        POW(COS(RADIANS(users.location_lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(users.location_long) - RADIANS(-99.165660)), 2) +
        POW(COS(RADIANS(19.391124)) * SIN(RADIANS(users.location_lat)) - 
       SIN(RADIANS(19.391124)) * cos(RADIANS(users.location_lat)) * cos(RADIANS(users.location_long) - RADIANS(-99.165660)), 2)
    )
    ,
    SIN(RADIANS(19.391124)) * 
    SIN(RADIANS(users.location_lat)) + 
    COS(RADIANS(19.391124)) * 
    COS(RADIANS(users.location_lat)) * 
    COS(RADIANS(users.location_long) - RADIANS(-99.165660))
 ) * 6371000) as distance,
users.id
FROM users
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

radius of the earth : 6371000 ( in meters)

Answer (score 3):

```
simpledb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tablename + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY   AUTOINCREMENT,lat double,lng double,address varchar)");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(lat,lng,address)values('22.2891001','70.780154','craftbox');");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(lat,lng,address)values('22.2901396','70.7782428','kotecha');");//22.2904718 //70.7783906
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(lat,lng,address)values('22.2863155','70.772108','kkv Hall');");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(lat,lng,address)values('22.275993','70.778076','nana mava');");
            simpledb.execSQL("insert into '" + tablename + "'(lat,lng,address)values('22.2667148','70.7609386','Govani boys hostal');");


    double curentlat=22.2667258;  //22.2677258
    double curentlong=70.76096826;//70.76096826

    double curentlat1=curentlat+0.0010000;
    double curentlat2=curentlat-0.0010000;

    double curentlong1=curentlong+0.0010000;
    double curentlong2=curentlong-0.0010000;

    try{

        Cursor c=simpledb.rawQuery("select * from '"+tablename+"' where (lat BETWEEN '"+curentlat2+"' and '"+curentlat1+"') or (lng BETWEEN         '"+curentlong2+"' and '"+curentlong1+"')",null);

        Log.d("SQL ", c.toString());
        if(c.getCount()>0)
        {
            while (c.moveToNext())
            {
                double d=c.getDouble(1);
                double d1=c.getDouble(2);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do a nearest neighbour search with some bound on the distance. SQL does not support anything like this as far as I am aware and you would need to use an alternative data structure such as an [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).

Answer (score 2):

MS SQL Edition here:

```
        DECLARE @SLAT AS FLOAT
        DECLARE @SLON AS FLOAT

        SET @SLAT = 38.150785
        SET @SLON = 27.360249

        SELECT TOP 10 [LATITUDE], [LONGITUDE], SQRT(
            POWER(69.1 * ([LATITUDE] - @SLAT), 2) +
            POWER(69.1 * (@SLON - [LONGITUDE]) * COS([LATITUDE] / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
        FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should just use PostGIS, SpatialLite, SQLServer2008, or Oracle Spatial. They can all answer this question for you with spatial SQL.

Comment: sounds like you should just NOT suggest that people switch their entire database platform and cause irrelevant results to show up in my google search when i explicitly search fro "Oracle"...

Answer (score 1):

```
 +----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| id | email                 | name    | location_lat | location_long |
+----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
| 7  | test@gmail.com        | rembo   | 23.0249256   |  72.5269697   |
| 25 | test1@gmail.com.      | Rajnis  | 23.0233221    | 72.5342112   |
+----+-----------------------+---------+--------------+---------------+
```

$lat = 23.02350629;

$long = 72.53230239;

DB::
SELECT
("
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT
*,
(
( ( acos( sin(( ". $ lat ." * pi() / 180)) * sin(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) + cos(( ". $ lat ."* pi() / 180 )) * cos(( `lat` * pi() / 180)) * cos((( ". $ long ." - `LONG`) * pi() / 180))) ) * 180 / pi() ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
)
as distance
FROM
`users`
)
users
WHERE
distance <= 2");

Comment: You could format the query to improve readability. Also, when pasting code use the appropriate tags so it´s displayed correctly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain what is going on here aswell. Like this is just a copy-pasted answer

Answer (score 0):

In extreme cases this approach fails, but for performance, I've skipped the trigonometry and simply calculated the diagonal squared.

Answer (score -1):

Mysql query for search coordinates with distance limit and where condition

```
 SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('28.5850154') ) * cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('77.07207489999999') ) + sin( radians('28.5850154') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `vendors` HAVING distance < 5;
```

Answer (score -22):

This problem is not very hard at all, but it gets more complicated if you need to optimize it.

What I mean is, do you have 100 locations in your database or 100 million? It makes a big difference.

If the number of locations is small, get them out of SQL and into code by just doing ->

```
Select * from Location
```

Once you get them into code, calculate the distance between each lat/lon and your original with the Haversine formula and sort it.