# Find nearest locations to a point with sql in Grails 2.1.1

Tags: sql, hql, nearest-neighbor, having-clause, grails-2.1

I am using Grails 2.1.1 and have to find all nearest locations for a given point. My code is looking like this (works in my app):

```
def findNearLocations(double latitude, double longitude) {
    def locationsFromQuery = Location.executeQuery(
        "SELECT id,(6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:ulatitude - abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +" +
        "COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) *" +
        "POWER(SIN((:ulongitude - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))))*1000 as distance " +
        "FROM Location WHERE is_public = TRUE ORDER BY distance", //  HAVING distance < 1000
        [ulatitude: latitude.toString().toDouble(), ulongitude: longitude.toString().toDouble()])
    // do stuff with locationsFromQuery
}
```

The formula for the computation of the nearest locations I used for is [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database) but I cannot use the HAVING clause like in the comment. If I use it, I get an hql.hibernate exception, saying, that there is an unexpected identifier HAVING. But why this is working in nearly all examples in google but not working for me?

I am using the h2 database in the memory.

Comment: Which is your database?

Comment: I am using the h2 in memory database of the grails h2 database plugin.

Comment: Try to put the sql comand in a subquery, like : `select id, distance from (select id, yourcalc as distance from location where is_public = true) order by distance having distance < 1000` The HAVING is not working probably because H2 doesn't allow to use an alias created in the same query. Try that and let me know.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I think there is something not working. I get an exception

`unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 26 [SELECT id, distance FROM (SELECT id,(6371 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((:ulatitude - abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2),2) +COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((:ulongitude - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2))))*1000 as distance FROM de.carmeq.carmob.Location WHERE is_public = TRUE) ORDER BY distance HAVING distance < 300]. Stacktrace follows:`

Comment: It is possible that your calc expression has some mistake. Try to test it step by step put the internal parts of the calc `COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) ` then `COS(:ulatitude * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) ` and go on until you find it

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ok, I will test it and send you a comment, soon. thx for the hints :)

Comment: There is also a latlong plugin on grails