# Find near by places of specific angle - consider only half circle of front not the back in round circle query

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I know how to find near by locations from MySQL database using Round circle radius query and I have given answer of the same on another SO question as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database/11113010#11113010).

But I wish to do some different thing from this now. Here what happened is the query returns the result from center of the point which includes entire circle of radius. I wish to get points only of the half circle. I know this is possible and its all mathematical calculation and I am little weak in it that's why asking for experts help.

See this image, it will give very clear idea.[image: Only front part location is needed, not the back side part. Need to ignore the back side part.]

As you can see in the image only front part location is needed, not the back side part. Need to ignore the back side part. Also I have divided the radius in different color to make them appear as zones - like red is zone1, orange is zone 2 and yellow is zone 3. This are virtual zones to filter the data (locations).

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot points inside a segment using Haversine/Spherical Law of Cosines for the radius. Then use pointInPolygon() to find only those within segment.  You will also require function to create polygon.

```
polySides = number of sides in polygon
pointLatArr = Lat of point in in polygon array
pointLngArr = Lng of point in in polygon array
dat.lat = Lat from Haversine results
dat.lng = Lng from Haversine results

if (pointInPolygonpolySides,pointLatArr,pointLngArr,dat.lat,dat.lng)){
     var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat,dat.lng); 
     addMarker(latlng,dat.name);
     bounds.extend(latlng);
  }

 function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
 var j = polySides-1 ;
  oddNodes = 0;
  for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
    if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
        if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
            oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
        }
    }
   j=i; }

  return oddNodes;
}
```

Function for segment polygon

```
function drawSegment(start,end,radius) { 
var d2r = Math.PI / 180;
pointLatArr = new Array();
pointLngArr = new Array();
polyLatLngs = new Array(); // latLngs of polygon
var polyLat = (radius /3963.189) / d2r; // miles
var polyLng = polyLat / Math.cos(center.lat() * d2r);
var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(),center.lng());//Center to start
pointLatArr.push(center.lat());
pointLngArr.push(center.lng());
polyLatLngs.push(centerLatLng);
bounds.extend(centerLatLng);
// Create polygon points (extra point to close polygon)
for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    // Convert degrees to radians
    var theta = i * d2r;
    var pointLat = center.lat() + (polyLat * Math.sin(theta));
    var pointLng = center.lng() + (polyLng * Math.cos(theta));
    var pointLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(pointLat), parseFloat(pointLng));
    polyLatLngs.push(pointLatLng);
    pointLatArr.push(pointLat);
    pointLngArr.push(pointLng);
    bounds.extend(pointLatLng);
}
var centerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(center.lat(),center.lng());//End to center
polyLatLngs.push(centerLatLng);
pointLatArr.push(center.lat());
pointLngArr.push(center.lng());
polySides = polyLatLngs.length;
```

Map using this technique
[image]
    }

See [**Demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/polygon/MapPolygonArc1.php)

Comment: can you share this map link? Is it available online? If yes I would like to check it online so I can test some scenarios.

Comment: @Scorpion Demo added to Answer