# Python Flask translating calculation for radius filter based on latitude & longitude to SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to implement a calculation for a radius:

I have a DB with rooms, every single room has a different adress and also a latiude and longitude.

A user can enter a cityname in a searchform to search for rooms in this city. Here I want to show a result page with rooms in the searched city + all rooms in other cities in a 60 km radius from the searched city.

[Here](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates) I found some solutions which I would like to try, but I cant figure out how to translate this into an SQLalchemy query:

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) * 6371 <= 60;
```

So theoretically I have to replace `1.3963` and `-0.6981` with the latitude and longitude of the searched city and I will get what I want.

Comment: Your question related this one maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26998576/5802335

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution in sqlalchemy:

`loc` is the location which someone searches for. For example a user entering a cityname.

`Zimmer` is my table, where all DB entries are, every `Zimmer` has a lat and lng, these are used to calculate the radius of the input `loc`. To limit the radius we use `<= 100` (for 100km).

```
all_rooms_in_city = Zimmer.query.filter(func.acos(func.sin(func.radians(loc_latitude)) * func.sin(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lat)) + func.cos(func.radians(loc_latitude)) * func.cos(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lat)) * func.cos(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lng) - (func.radians(loc_longitude)))) * 6371 <= 100)
```

Ordering is also possible by simply putting the same code in an `order_by()` and leave out the limiting `<= 100` radius:

```
.order_by(asc(func.acos(func.sin(func.radians(loc_latitude)) * func.sin(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lat)) + func.cos(func.radians(loc_latitude)) * func.cos(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lat)) * func.cos(func.radians(Zimmer.zimmer_lng) - (func.radians(loc_longitude)))) * 6371))
```

Dont forget here to import func from sqlalchemy, because otherwise the math methods wont work in the query. If you have saved your lat and lng in a Radians Column in your database you dont need the typecast. I used `func.radians()` because my lat and lng where saved in a Float Column

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQL alchemy's `from_statement(statement)` method, as described here :

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html

With this, you do not need to translate this to SQL Alchemy "syntax", the QueryAPI will do it for you.

So you could do something like:

```
q = session.query(PlacesClass).from_statement(
    'SELECT * FROM Places WHERE acos(sin(1.3963) * sin(Lat) + '\
    'cos(1.3963) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - (-0.6981))) * 6371 <= 60;')
```

Answer (score 0):

Though @Roman's answer above give me the basic idea how to achieve this, however, his solution didn't work for me. So, here is my solution:

```py
Location.query.filter(
    (func.degrees(
        func.acos(
            func.sin(func.radians(lat)) * func.sin(func.radians(Location.latitude)) + 
            func.cos(func.radians(lat)) * func.cos(func.radians(Location.latitude)) * 
            func.cos(func.radians(lon-Location.longitude))
        )
    ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344) <= distance)
```

Here `lat` and `lon` is the given coords from where I was calculating the distance. The distance was limited by given `distance` in the query. This query is calculating the distance in `km`, if you want to calculate in `mile`, remove the `* 1.609344` from the query.