# Python flask jinja2 use math module sin() cos() in template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am currently implementing a radius filter system.

A user can search for a room in a city and based on the latitude and longitude of the searched city the result page will show all other rooms in a 60 km radius.

I have found a working function, which I already tested (eventhough the numbers are way too high, the relative proportians are still showing the correct results):

```
acos(sin(loc_latitude) * sin(zimmer.zimmer_lat) + cos(loc_latitude) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lat) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lng - (loc_longitude))) * 6371 <= 6000:
```

I need this as a jinja if expression:

```
{% if acos(sin(loc_latitude) * sin(zimmer.zimmer_lat) + cos(loc_latitude) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lat) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lng - (loc_longitude))) * 6371 <= 6000 %}
```

But in the template jinja does not know the cos() and sin() functions which I imported from the math module:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\Eclipse-Workspace\Monteurzimmer\templates\zimmer_gefunden.html", line 149, in block "content"
{% if acos(sin(loc_latitude) * sin(zimmer.zimmer_lat) + cos(loc_latitude) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lat) * cos(zimmer.zimmer_lng - (loc_longitude))) * 6371 <= 60 %} 
UndefinedError: 'sin' is undefined
```

Is there a way to pass these functions to the template?

I saw this:

```
your_template.render(sin())
your_template.render(cos())
```

But I do not understand where to get your_template, because I am already rendering the template like this:

```
return render_template('zimmer_gefunden.html', mymap=mymap, paginator_find=paginator_find, findroomcity=findroomcity, 
                    form=form, pagenumber_find=pagenumber_find, all_rooms_in_city=all_rooms_in_city, pages_list_find=pages_list_find, all_einzelzimmer = all_einzelzimmer,
                    all_doppelzimmer = all_doppelzimmer, all_mehrbettzimmer = all_mehrbettzimmer, all_wohnung = all_wohnung,
                    loc_latitude = loc_latitude, loc_longitude = loc_longitude)
```

Or is there an other approach?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the result in Python on the server side and pass the result to your template?

Comment: You mean with an SQL statement? I would have to use .from_statement because SQLalchemy cannot make such a calculation and because of that I get tons of problems. Because I used .from_statement all other SQLalchemy filter and order functions do not work anymore. So I chose this way. Here is my older question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804240/python-flask-translating-calculation-for-radius-filter-based-on-latitude-longi

Comment: I don't see any SQL involved here. Maybe you should include that in the Question. I actually meant pure Python code.

Comment: Thats also a good Idea to make it in python code, will consider it, because I still have to figure out how to sort the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/templating/#context-processors):

> To inject new variables automatically into the context of a template, context processors exist in Flask. Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to inject new values into the template context. A context processor is a function that returns a dictionary. The keys and values of this dictionary are then merged with the template context, for all templates in the app

Basically, just add this to your code and you'll be able to use those functions in all your templates.

```
from math import sin, cos, acos

@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    return dict(cos=cos, sin=sin, acos=acos)
```

Add any other functions or variables to the returned `dict` to make them available to your templates.

Comment: I already solved it with:  app.jinja_env.globals.update(the_cos=cos)
 app.jinja_env.globals.update(the_sin=sin)
 app.jinja_env.globals.update(the_acos=acos) Is this a good solution?

Comment: It is better and cleaner to go the standard Flask way if you are using Flask, but your solution should also work, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Roman I use only jinja (not Flask), and your solution looks much better (easier and robust) to me. Please make it a separate answer!