# SQL search "near" longitude and latitude

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a search bar that searches near a location. For now it's hard coded. The statement works until I add the like statements for longitude and latitude. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$searchString = explode(' ', $_GET["searchString"]);
$useLocation = $_GET["useCurrentLocation"]; 
if($useLocation == 1){
    foreach($searchString AS $key){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE Name LIKE '%{$key}%' AND Longitude Like '-79.8579' And Latitude Like '43.5237'"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['Name'];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find many solution on internet about "how to search by location"

There are some answer on Stackoverflow:

- [How to find nearest location using latitude and longitude from sql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/how-to-best-implement-nearest-neighbour-search-in-mysql
- [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)

Or on Google:

- http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/

Here is my last query about that:

> I get the longitude/latitude via Google Maps API. Enter an address,
>   and get back the GPS coordinate.
>   After, calculate with SQL the position and the objects around

$longitude_ref = 7.694731;
$latitude_ref = 48.560719;

```
SELECT *
  FROM maps
  WHERE (
    6366 *
    acos(
      cos(radians(48.560719)) -- $latitude_ref
      *
      cos(radians(`latitude`))
      *
      cos(radians(`longitude`) - radians($longitude_ref)) -- $longitude_ref
      +
      sin(radians(48.560719)) * sin(radians(`latitude`)) -- $latitude_ref
    )
  ) <= 2 -- r in Km (here: 2 km)
```

You can also calculate the distance between two points:

```
SELECT pg.id, pg.*, pg1.*, 6366 * 2 *
    atan2(
      sqrt(
        SIN((RADIANS(pg1.latitude) - RADIANS(pg.latitude)) / 2) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.latitude) - RADIANS(pg.latitude)) / 2) + COS(RADIANS(pg.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(pg1.latitude)) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.longitude) - RADIANS(pg.longitude)) / 2) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.longitude) - RADIANS(pg.longitude)) / 2)    
      ),
      sqrt(
        1 - SIN((RADIANS(pg1.latitude) - RADIANS(pg.latitude)) / 2) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.latitude) - RADIANS(pg.latitude)) / 2) + COS(RADIANS(pg.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(pg1.latitude)) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.longitude) - RADIANS(pg.longitude)) / 2) * SIN((RADIANS(pg1.longitude) - RADIANS(pg.longitude)) / 2)
      )
    ) as calculated_distance_final_km
  FROM perso_gps pg
  WHERE pg.calculated_dist IS NULL
```

Many examples on internet :)