# How to search nearby location with kilometer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, location

I have the database like as below structure. And how can I get location_id in list within 5 kilometer. There have latitude and longitude numbers are already in the database table. Please see my database structure image.

```
- school_id
- location_id
- school_name
- lat
- lng
```

Here is the database structure image:

[image]

I have already searched from this link 
[How to find nearest location using latitude and longitude from sql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database)
and i don't understand the code.

> SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
>   cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(
>   radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25
>   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#finding-locations-with-mysql

Comment: Yeah. I already saw that post. But i don't understand what is radians and how can i get that radians. Please explain me code.

Answer (score 14):

The constant literal **3959** represents an approximation of the radius of the earth, in miles. That's why the "great circle distance" expression is returning a value in miles.

To get distance in kilometers, just replace **3959** with **6371**, an approximation of the earth's radius in km.

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

---

What the query is doing is calculating a distance (in miles) between two points on the earth, represented by degrees latitude and degrees longitude.

One the points is represented by literal values in the GCD expression  **(37.000000,-122.000000)**. The other point is **(lat,lng)** (degrees latitude and degrees longitude) from the row in the database.

The query cranks through every row in the table, and evaluates the GCD expression to calculate a distance. (The length of shortest line along the surface of the sphere between the two points.)

The `HAVING distance < 25` clause excludes any row where the calculated distance is either greater than or equal to 25 or NULL.

The `ORDER BY distance` clause returns the rows in sequence by ascending values of distance, the closest points first.

The `LIMIT 20` clause restricts the return to the first twenty rows.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Within five kilometers of *what*?  The Santa Monica Pier Aquarium?

That's latitude 34.010396, longitude -118.496029.

We can set user-defined variables (to avoid spreading literals in our query text):

```
 SET @lat =   34.010396 ;
 SET @lng = -118.496029 ;
```

Our SQL text include in the SELECT list the columns we want to return from our table. We'll also included a complicated looking "Great Circle Distance" expression that returns a distance in kilometers.

Something Like this:

```
 SELECT m.school_id
      , m.location_id
      , m.school_name
      , m.lat
      , m.lng

      , ( ACOS( COS( RADIANS( @lat  ) ) 
              * COS( RADIANS( m.lat ) )
              * COS( RADIANS( m.lng ) - RADIANS( @lng ) )
              + SIN( RADIANS( @lat  ) )
              * SIN( RADIANS( m.lat ) )
          )
        * 6371
        ) AS distance_in_km

  FROM mytable m
 ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
 LIMIT 100
```

The GCD formula in the expression is calculating a distance between *two* points.

In this query, one of the points is a *constant* `(@lat,@lng)`, which we previously set to the coordinates of the Santa Monica Pier Aquarium.

The other point is `(m.lat,m.lng)`, the latitude and longitude from the row in the table.

So in this query, `distance_in_km` represents the distance between `(lat,lng)` of the row in the table and the Santa Monica Pier Aquarium.

Because `distance_in_km` value is *not* available at the time the rows are accessed, we can't reference that in a `WHERE` clause.

But we can reference it in a `HAVING` clause. That's simliar to a `WHERE` in that it filters out rows, but is much different, because it is evaluated much later in the query execution. And it can reference expressions that aren't available when the rows are being accessed, when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.

We can modify our query to include the HAVING clause.  In this case, we're limiting to rows that are within 100 kilometers, and we'll return only the closest 12 rows...

```
  FROM mytable m
HAVING distance_in_km <= 100
 ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC
 LIMIT 12
```

If we want to find the distance to some point other than the Santa Monica Pier, we set `@lat` and `@lng` for that point, and re-execute the SQL.

Comment: im the same question and use it for my gis locations that i have and this is worked properly thanks @spencer7593

Comment: Works perfectly for me even with active records. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN(inputLat * PI() / 180) * 
SIN(tableColLat * PI() / 180) + COS(inputLat * PI() / 180) * 
COS(tableColLat * PI() / 180) * COS((inputLng - tableColLng) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
as distance FROM gm_shop HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

distance is you can change. it is KM

Answer (score 0):

When I solved a similar problem instead of worrying about curvature of the earth and angles. I just used the Pythagorean distance. It's a close enough approximation IMHO.

i.e. getting all schools that are in an approximate 5km Pythagorean distances.

```
select sqrt(pow(lat - curlat,2) + pow(lng - curlng,2)) as distance from markers having distance < XXXXX
```

You'll have to calculate the approximate value for XXXX.  I degree is approximately 111km. If you aren't doing any extreme latitudes you shouldn't have to worry about  adjusting it. So you could set XXXX at 0.045

Comment: Because lines of longitude converge away from the equator, if you use this technique the Pythagorean distance pulls in too many points.