# Python: How to calculate latitude of multiple point using the latitude of one point and distance between them?

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps, distance, latitude-longitude

Let's clarify the issue. I want to find the location of nearest ATM booths from my house. I have the latitude and longitude values of my location and a distance value let's say 500 meter around my house. I need to find the locations (latitudes) of ATM booths 500 meter around my house.
Input value: 1. latitude of my house,
2. Distance in meter

Asking for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Where are the ATM locations stored? Why do you only want the latitudes of the ATMs and not the longitudes?

Comment: Locations are stored in mysql database as a latitude and longitude. I want to use latitude because it can easily be converted as kilometers or meter as it's value is more consistent than longitude.

Comment: But it probably won't be possible to measure the actual distance only based on latitudes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112926/how-to-find-nearest-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-from-sql-database

Comment: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html

Comment: Google Maps' Places API Nearby Search can help you achieve this. It's a service that lets you search for places within a specified area: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: Since you use MySQL, you can probably use the spatial convenience functions, and have MySQL actually return you the distance between the house and all the points see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere