# Searching among 2D vectors with less effort

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a table of 2D points (geographical coordinates) in database. What is a best practice to organize the data to make search a row with most closest coordinates to the given among this array of data?

I cannot figure out anything better than:

```
SELECT * FROM `pois` WHERE 1 
ORDER BY ($x-`x`)*($x-`x`) + ($y-`y`)*($y-`y`) ASC LIMIT 1
```

This approach can be acceptable if the table size is 1000 rows. But it can be terribly slow if the `poi` DB is 1 million of rows...

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Geo Distance Search](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching in a circle, search in a square using `BETWEEN` so SQL can utilize the indices on X and Y which hopefully you already have.

Then do the full circle check on the subset of data you get back.