# Find Nearest Place By Using My SQL Record Of LATITUDE And LONGITUDE

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, geolocation

I have a mySql table named `tbl_places` 
This contains fields 
`Place_id`, `PlaceName`, `Place_LATITUDE`, `place_LONGITUDE`.

I want to use it in the `place detail` page now 
If the current `place_id` of the open page is 4 then I want a maximum 6 records nearest to that place.

Suppose the current place is:

```
 place_id = 4
 place_name = Lal Killa
 place_LATITUDE = 77.2413969039917
 place_LONGITUDE = 28.653838307772872
```

I can't understand how to find nearest place to the current place??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find nearest latitude/longitude with an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/find-nearest-latitude-longitude-with-an-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query:

```sql
SELECT
    Place_id,
    PlaceName,
    (
        3959 
        * acos(
            cos( radians(37) ) 
            * cos( radians( Place_LATITUDE ) ) 
            * cos( radians( Place_LONGITUDE ) - radians(-122) ) 
            + sin( radians(37) ) 
            * sin( radians( Place_LATITUDE ) ) 
        ) 
    ) AS distance 
FROM tbl_places 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

NOTE - Here latitude = 37 & longitude = -122

Also, check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#creating-the-table) for more reference.

Comment: What is the Meaning of "distance < 25"

Comment: 25 is the distance in miles. This will find the closest 20 locations that are within a radius of 25 miles to the 37, -122 coordinate.

Comment: To search by kilometers instead of miles, replace 3959 with 6371. 25 will be in kilometer then

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Cohen–Sutherland (point clipping) algorithm to know the people near by, if you want to minimize the result,set it as a incremental order from 0 to YOUR_LIMIT.

it is better than a formula that convert a polar co-ordinates[(ie)lat and long] to XY

Answer (score 0):

We can find distance in mile and kilometer

For mile

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",


  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));*/
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

for kilometer

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT usermail, res_name, lat, lng, ( 6371  * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM mstuser HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",


  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
```

Please check in this url : https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2015/12/get-near-by-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-php-in-kilometer.html

Comment: You need to disclose your affiliation every time you link to your own blog.