# Find nearest objects without lat/lon pari

Tags: objective-c

I have about 2.2M objects which all contain a full address (street, state, zip), however none of them have a lat/lon pair.

How can I sort an array to find the nearest objects to a location? Is there a way to do it with the ZIP code?

Comment: Update your data with coordinates.

Comment: @rmaddy There is nearly 2.2M objects, thats going to cost quite a bit. I'm hoping there is another way.

Comment: You only need to update the data once. Otherwise you have to do very expensive lookup for every record every time you wish to sort.

Comment: Why did you revert the tags? Your question has absolutely nothing at all to do with Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy Because my question has absolutely nothing to do with iOS. I didn't even mention iOS or an app anywhere in my question. This could be about OS X, or even a command line program.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few methods:

1. You can find coordinates of location by address.
   This technique is called geocoding. IOS already have built-in classes to do that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html
2. You also can use any other paydable geocoding service (like google) in any platform without rate restriction.
3. Or you can do it by yourself with this https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666 by storing it in any local DB (like sqlite) and then associating object zipcode to its coordinates.
   And then find nearest zipcodes to your object -
   [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc) It's not accurate method, but will work.