# Spatialite SQL query to find the nearest node for the given lat/lon

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, spatialite

I want to find the nearest node to a given coordinate. I checked this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186783/how-to-get-the-long-lat-information-from-a-nodeid-and-vice-versa
But, his answer doesn't work.

My query:

```
SELECT PID, 
    min (DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), MakePoint(-79.417589, 43.266571)))
    FROM test1f
```

There is no synax error, but no matter what the point is, it always returns the first record in the database and the distance to it.

I also tried this query

```
SELECT PID, 
      DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), MakePoint(-79.917589, 43.266571))
    FROM test1f  ORDER BY DISTANCE(Startpoint(geometry), MakePoint(-79.917589, 43.266571))
```

I got 50000 results, the first one is what I want. How can I only get the first one?

Comment: I think you need to Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc) hope that help

Comment: I think you need to Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc) hope that help

Comment: @MarioNassef That has nothing to do with SpatiaLite.

Comment: Did you try using a `LIMIT`?

Comment: Please make a [mcve], e.g. by posting the result of `.dump` from SQLite command line tool of a suitably tailored toy database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query looks correct. (It is essentially identical with the [first example here](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN).)

Anyway, to return only the first result row, add [LIMIT 1](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset) to the query.

Since SpatiaLite 4.4.0, you can use the [KNN virtual table](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN) to do the search more efficiently:

```
SELECT test1f.PID,
       knn.distance
FROM test1f
JOIN knn ON test1f.PID = knn.fid  -- assuming PID is the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
WHERE f_table_name = 'test1f'
  AND ref_geometry = MakePoint(-79.417589, 43.266571)
  AND max_items = 1;
```

Comment: My version is 3.01. knn is not supported.. Is there someway else to do it? I am not sure why, the first query doesn't work.

Comment: Then use the LIMIT.