# MySQL - Find Closest Match in range of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a graph type application and I'm looking to find the best solution within a x,y axis start to end point.

MySQL Data:

[image]

Say I have the following:
starting_x: 200
starting_y: 150
ending_x: 500
ending_y: 605

So I'm wanting to find the **closest** match between the above numbers to the database.

My query I'm working with now:

```
SELECT * FROM `graph` ORDER BY `start_pos_x`,`start_pos_y`,`end_pos_x`,`end_pos_y` ASC
```

I know this is not even close to what I'm trying to do but i'm having a hard time finding a solution on here.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe your question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc

Comment: How do you define "closest" for your comparison?  Minimum total distance between starting points and between ending points?  Minimum area of the trapezoid formed by connecting endpoints?  Something else?

Comment: minimum total distance so the closest x, y to the closest x, ,y in database.

Comment: For next time, please don't provide pictures of data. Just provide the data (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an algorithm question.
First, you must define `the closest match between the above numbers to the database`. For example, I can define it as to find "the lowest sum of the squares of the differences between Xs and of Ys."
Then, the solution might be something like:

```
Select 
  * 
From 
  `graph` 
Order by
  Power(starting_x-200, 2) + Power(starting_y-150, 2) 
  + Power(ending_x-500, 2) + Power(ending_y-605, 2) ASC
```