# Sort document by child location

Tags: solr, nested, spatial

I am indexing product documents as shown in the snippet below and I want to 
 sort the products according to the shops which are stored as child documents of the product.

```
{
  id: "101",
  title: "product title",
  nodeType: "product",
  ...
  _childDocuments_: [
    {
      id: "12432",
      name: "shop-name",
      quantity: 12,
      location: "42.1218,16.5432",
      nodeType: "shop"
    },
    {
      id: "14811",
      name: "shop-name-2",
      quantity: 0,
      location: "46.2995,14.9546",
      nodeType: "shop"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

indexing and filtering works fine but when I try to sort the results by distance of the children documents with the following sort-query it just does not work at all.

`{!parent which="nodeType:product" v='nodeType:shop dist(2,latitude,longitude,48.185378,16.400646)'}asc`

another sort-query I've tried:

`{!parent which="nodeType:product"}{!geofilt sfield=location}&pt=48.1984032,16.3821551&d=5`

this last one will always return infinity for geodist() and not give me the expected sorting.

I am really stuck with this. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify which part does not work - the query results or the expected sort?

Comment: the expected sort does not work

Comment: I am not seeing a sort in your query - just an "asc" (which seems part of the query?)

Comment: the stated query is just the "sort=" part. the rest of the query can be anything

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how to sort based on lat,lan points with respect to shop.
If that is the case I see there is something specific for this problem: [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc?noredirect=1&lq=1)