# Filtering out GPS coordinates that are within same radius

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I have a list with nearly 100,000 GPS coordinates in lat/long format in a CSV file. A lot of these are only a few inches away from each other, so I would like to merge them somehow, or filter those out that are too close together within a certain radius.

Do you guys know of a script or a service that can do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reference to a nice paper that explains how to find nearest lat/lng points inside a specified bounding box in another thread, which you can find here: [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)

Here is the direct link to the paper: [Geo Distance Search with MySQL](https://de.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

I think you can adapt the idea from the paper to your domain in order to set up a filter procedure.

Comment: Perfect! That definitely looks like something I can use. Thanks!