# Distance between two locations in Laravel using latitude and longitude in database query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called warehouses, which has *latitude & longitude* columns. I am searching nearby warehouses from my current location *(Providing latitude & longitude, radius)* to find the warehouses nearby me in a given radius.

this operation needs to be performed by the query, not manual functions.

Comment: You should check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/find-nearest-latitude-longitude-with-an-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

For those who might need it, I have solved this problem.

```
$lati = (float)$request->latitude;
$longt = (float)$request->longtitude;
$rad = (int)$request->radius;



$distance_result = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians($lati))
* cos(radians(latit))
* cos(radians(longt)
- radians($longt))
+ sin(radians($lati))
* sin(radians(latit))))";


$warhouses = Warhouse::select('id', 'name')
    ->selectRaw("{$distance_result} AS distance")
    ->whereRaw("{$distance_result} < ?", [$rad])
    ->get();



return view('test')->with('nearbys', $warhouses);
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this query? I am doing similar work, but I don't know what is 6371 in there. and also how these formulas are actually working,

Answer (score 0):

Use This mysql Function :
[ST_Distance_Sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)

Supported since MySql 5.7 version and above.

`select ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lon,lat), point(lon,lat))`