# Work out the nearest users MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, geolocation

I have a database named `users` with the columns `latitude` and `longitude`, and I want to work out the nearest users (users in the `users` table) which are within a 50km radius to a certain latitude and longitude provided by `$_POST`.

Can you tell me how I could do that? Is there a certain mathematical function that needs to be used, or a function in MySQL like `latitude_compare()` or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proximity Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260335/proximity-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT *,

(ACOS((SIN(RADIANS(ref_latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(latitude))) + 
(COS(RADIANS(ref_latitude))*COS(RADIANS( latitude ))*COS(RADIANS( longitude)
-RADIANS(ref_longitude)))) * 6371) AS distance

FROM table
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Point A:
ref_latitude
ref_longitude

Point B:
latitude 
longitude

My Lat/Lon Values are in degrees, like this one:

Dresden: 13.721067614881400 / 51.060033646337900

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code I have been using, this is in miles. It selects all lat and lng within given radius.

```
$q = "SELECT * ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians($current_lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($current_lng) ) + sin( radians($current_lat) ) * sin( radians( lat )))) AS distance FROM users HAVING distance < $radius";
```