# How to find nearest location coordinates among list of locations from current location?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, annotations, mkmapview, coordinates

I am developing an Iphone monotouch application.

I am getting list of locations from server, i want to display only **nearest** location on the map among the list of locations.

please provide me related link, thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location has latitude and lognitude. First sort by latitude and get the closest latitudes (+-x).
Then filter again by closest longitudes(+-x). Then you have your points.

Comment: Hi specialscope, can you please provide me any code or releated link

Comment: What you are looking for is called proximity search. Search stackoverflow for that you will get plenty. For eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260335/proximity-search

Comment: i am trying the above 3 lines of code but i did not found the  System.Device.Location  assemly or namespace, can you please provide me the dll.Please

Comment: Don't just use the numerically nearest lat and long unless all your points are very close to each other. 1 degree of longitude = 1 degree of latitude at the equator, but no where else. The lat/long grid is not square.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Distance Matrix API. Using this API you can calculate distances between any  given positions.