# Make a rank between places distances

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying order by desc distances. I have a database which contains a column called `latlong` (latitude and longitude) and another one called `user_id`. I have a function that calculates the distances between two places by using the `latlong` in MySQL and it returns the distance in kilometers.

```
function calc($latlong1,$latlong2);
```

So, I would like to make a query that I can order by all the places by the near distance between each other. For example: Place A is near Place C then Place B. So the rank will be: Place A, Place C then Place B.

Comment: Most RDBMS that store geometry have a distance function such as st_distance(geom,geom) which returns a double

Comment: Note that a database contains tables, and tables contain columns.  You've not mentioned the table names.  It is also not clear what the relevance of `user_id` is.

Comment: I forgot that right. My user_id refers a latlong . But I think that is not necessary user_id for doing this.

Comment: markg I have already a function for calc the distance. My problem is making a rank by near places like I said.

Comment: do you want to sort by how close a place is to a specific place (eg the user's place), or to any other place?

Comment: I want to sort by how close a place is to any other place in the mysql.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proximity Search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260335/proximity-search)