# Find the nearest longitude and latitude

Tags: python, django, latitude-longitude

I have a table with latitude and longitude columns with 1000 rows

I want when I give latitude and longitude It should return a matching lat-long result

and if lat and long are not found in the database can give the nearest lat long from the database table

table

```
------------------------------------------------|
id | name |      lat        |       long|       |
---|------|-----------------|-------------------|
1  | test |27.988865824076 | 77.8523526316      |
```

I am passing in the request body

```
{
    "latitude": 27.98681188240762,
    "longitude": 77.86585050166316
}
```

and expecting ht nearest matching result

Comment: can you share your models? Are you using Geo Django or just noraml database?

Comment: I'm using MySQL normal database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proximity Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260335/proximity-search)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/find-nearest-latitude-longitude-with-an-sql-query